# crypto.subtle is undefined even though I'm using http://localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, cryptography, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to use `crypto.subtle.digest()` as part of a checksum function for a file upload project I'm working on but for some reason I keep getting the following error:

```
upload-form.tsx:129 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'digest')
```

Which suggests that `crypto.subtle` is undefined. I understand that `crypto.subtle` is [only available in a secure contexts (HTTPS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/subtle), but I am trying to use it within `http://localhost:3000` which I read was [also considered a secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts). I have tried it in both Chrome & Firefox, and get the same undefined error in both.

## For Context:

I am using `NextJS 14.1.0` and `Node.js v20.11.0`

I tested this on `http://localhost:3000` on `Chrome v121.0.6167.160` and `Firefox ESR v115.3.0esr`

I am using `import * as crypto from "crypto"` within a Client Component (I have `"use client";` at the top)

This is the checksum function I'm using which I got from this [Youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/t-lhgq7Nfpc?si=etnjsj5IwM2h9Iyv&t=1486) but only briefly shows it.

The comments are from ChatGPT who also came up with basically the same function.

```
//upload-form.tsx
"use client";

... //imports

import * as crypto from "crypto";

... //some code

const computeSHA256 = async (file: File) => {
  // Convert file to an array buffer
  const buffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
  
  // Calculate SHA-256 hash
  const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", buffer);

  // Convert hashBuffer to hexadecimal representation
  const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));
  const hashHex = hashArray
    .map((byte) => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))
    .join("");

  return hashHex;
};

... //rest of file
```

Using `crypto.webcrypto.subtle.digest()`, I get the error:

```
upload-form.tsx:133 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subtle')
```

Which suggests that `crypto.webcrypto` is undefined.

**If I use `window.crypto.subtle.digest()` instead, then the function runs perfectly fine, but I am wondering if that is the right way to go about it.**

I used `console.log(crypto)` to see what properties it had, and neither `webcrypto` or `subtle` was there.

Directly printing `window.crypto` within Chrome's console shows that it does have `subtle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after looking into the [github repo](https://github.com/meech-ward/nextjs-s3-example/blob/main/src/app/create/create-post-form.tsx) provided by the owner of the [Youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/t-lhgq7Nfpc?si=etnjsj5IwM2h9Iyv&t=1486), I noticed that he never actually used `import crypto from 'crypto'` at the top of his file. I wondered how he was able to use crypto without importing it, but I guess it turns out that without the import, javascript/react/nextjs (??) will default the `crypto` variable to the Web Crypto API `crypto`.

I had no clue that this was a thing.

If my understanding is correct, then, this is the same as just using `window.crypto`, which was what I was using to get the function to work initially.

## To sum up:

- Remove the `import * as crypto from 'crypto;` at the top of the file
- The `crypto` variable will default to use `window.crypto`, aka the Web Crypto API
- `crypto.subtle.digest()` will work as intended.
- Alternatively you can just use `window.crypto.subtle.digest()` instead of the predefined `crypto` variable.